# How to play video when in browser viewport and stop at a certain time

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, media

Im building a Wordpress site, and I need a video to be played (started) when it enters the viewport, but it needs to pause at a certain time and remain there indefinitely.

To further your understanding, I have created a gif from the movie. and attached it here. Basically, I need the tiles to start falling when a user scrolls down to the video- and PAUSE and REMAIN PAUSED- once the tiles are all stacked ontop of each other. The reason why I say it should be paused, is because if you let the video end, the tiles all disappear and the video just sits with a black screen.

[image: StackGif]

Comment: Can't you cut the video to keep the last frame with all tiles showing ?

Comment: The last frame does contain that, but the video seems to "switch off" at the end. It just goes to a black box.